# Reset password nodejs y nodemailer

Tags: nodejs, express, jwt, nodemailer

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un reset de contraseña con con nodejs y nodemailer, mi problema está en cuando le doy click al link que me mando por correo, cuando trato de acceder a ese link desde mi mail, me devuelve un error **403 - forbidden**
Estoy utilizando **JWT** para crear mi token y mandar mi mail.

```
router.post('/get-reset-pass', (req, res) => {
    var os = require("os");
    var hostname = os.hostname();
    //check if user existe

    const mailuser = req.body.mail;
    const qu = pool.query('SELECT * from USERS_ where mail = ?', [mailuser]);

    qu.then((resx) => {
        if (resx.length > 0) {
            const user_ = res[0];

           //creando token con mail
            const user = mailuser;
            const token = jwt.sign({
                user
            }, 'process.env.SECRETO', {
                expiresIn: '3600s'
            });

            //mail de recuperación
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: "gmail",
                port: 25,
                secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
                auth: {
                    type: 'oauth2',
                    user: 'manuel.o@trustfund.com.mx',
                    clientId: 'xxxxx',
                    clientSecret: 'xxxxx',
                    refreshToken: 'xxxxx'
                }
            });
            const xname = 'TRUSTFUND';

            /*req.headers = {
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'authorization':'Bearer'
            }*/

            //host =    req.header('host');    
            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers.host));
            const hosty = req.headers.host;
            // send mail with defined transport object
            let mail = transporter.sendMail({
                from: '"TrustFundWeb  user: ' + xname + ' <' + mailuser + '>', // sender address
                to: "mimail@gmail.com", // list of receivers
                subject: "Reinicio de contraseña ✔", // Subject line
                text: 'Reinicio de contraseña',
                html: '<div class="card" style="width:400px">' +
                    '<div class="card-body">' +
                    '<h4 class="card-title">Mensaje de:' + xname + '</h4>' +
                    '<p class="card-text">Este espacio es para recuperar tu contraseña</p>' +
                    '<a href="https://'+hosty+'/reset-pass-confirm/'+ token + '">Click Aqui</a>' +
                    '<p class="card-text">' + mailuser + '</p>' +
                    '' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>',
            });


            console.log(token,mail);

            mail.then(() => {

                res.render('public/mensajenviado');

            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }else{
            req.flash('message', 'No existe usuario con ese mail');
            res.redirect('/reset-pass');
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });


});
```

Esta es la ruta que recibo

```
    router.get('/reset-pass-confirm/:token',isNotLoggedIn,ensureToken ,(req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.params);
    const {token} = req.params;
    //console.log(token);
    jwt.verify(token, 'process.env.SECRETO', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        } else {
        const sc = {tok: token}
            //console.log(data)
            res.render('auth/reset-pass',{sc});
        }
    });
});
```

Hice mi prueba en post man y tuve éxito, me devuelve mi vista para cambiar contraseñas, la cuestion es que tuve que agregar esto:

```
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'authorization':'Bearer'
```

en los headers, sin ellos me daba 403, entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de anexar estos headers a la liga que estoy mandando por mail.
O si me estoy saltando algo. Gracias

Comment: Hola, vuelvo a opinar que tienes una confusión en cómo deseas llevar a cabo tu proceso. O tal vez yo entiendo mal tu aplicación. Ejemplo: si yo soy un usuario de tu App y he olvidado mi password para ingresar, puedo solicitar un reset mediante un link en tu aplicación en la vista de `sign-in`. Tu App me enviará un correo, el cual tendrá un vínculo a una página de reset, la cual debe mostrarse sólo a quien incluya en la URL como parámetro un token válido, y algún otro parámetro que escojas (normalmente el correo del usuario). Por ende el token ha de ir en la URL y no en la cabecera (header)

Comment: Por lo tanto, tu App debe leer el token desde la URL y no esperarlo en la cabecera. Así mostrará la vista de reset sólo si el token es válido. No se si eso es lo que necesitas hacer. Si no, por favor explicame qué me pierdo de tu App. Tal vez soy yo el que no lo entiendo.

Comment: Así, tus middlewares `isNotLoggedIn` y `ensureToken` no tienen sentido en esa ruta, ya que yo no logro hacer login (porque olvidé el password) y por lo tanto no tendré un token de autorización para mi sesión de usuario. Tal vez si quitas esos middleware de tu ruta, lograrás lo que intentas. Saludos

Comment: todo bien, mando el token por la url, y lo recibo como parametro /:token 
Si yo mando desde postman un get con un token como parametro y en los headers content-type y auth , me devuelve la vista, pero si accedo a la vista desde mi gmail, o lo que sea me manda un forbidden, aún cuando le mando el token. Ese es el problema que tengo.

Comment: @MauricioContreras por ende yo supongo o imagino que debe haber una forma de mandar content-type y auth dentro de la url que estoy creando dentro de el transporter

Comment: Porque hay algo en tus middleware `isNotLoggedIn` y `ensureToken` que deben estar interfiriendo. Quita esos middleware de tu ruta y realiza la prueba.

Comment: si quito el ensureToken que sentido tiene mandar el token? @MauricioContreras

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94303/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim).